# How to make OnBoard go away?

Tags: onboard

Because I had a problem with my keyboard I enabled the on screen keyboard OnBoard. Now, I want to disable it, but I haven't been able to do so, even though I have googled for a solution.

Right now, the OnBoard screen doesn't appear on the lock screen, it just gets loaded on login and boot up and I want to disable that.

I have hidden the keyboard and the tray icon too, but I can still see it running with the ps command.

```
nuno@mozart:~$ ps -e | grep onboard
 4138 ?        00:00:01 onboard
```

I have also tried the onboard command at the terminal, but that doesn't give me any "don't run on boot up option".

And I have also checked the start up appliications "Startup Applications" and it wasn't there.

Any idea how I can disable it for sure? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If it automatically loads *after* logging in, clicking the four squares icon widget and choosing "Quit", or disabling it through **Settings -> Universal Access -> Typing -> Typing Assistant** should both yield the preferred result.

If it loads prior to logging in - mostly when returning from Suspension or Hibernation (or if the problem persists), use the following path:

- Open onBoard through **Settings -> Universal Access -> Typing**
- Click the button showing either 123 or multiple horizontal lines.
- Click the settings button.
- This opens **OnBoard Preferences** (comments on the command to skip the above lines would be nice, it's just the only way I know for sure)
- **General** tab -> **Desktop Integration** section -> untick **Show when unlocking the screen**

This should disable it globally for the launch/wake screen.
If this fails, the *Universal Access* icon should be somewhere on the launch screen as a widget as well. Changing the settings there should achieve a global result as well.